# Service vs Runnable vs AsyncTask

Tags: android

I'm developing a countdown timer app for Android. The app can show the remaining time. It has to be working even the phone is locked or the main activity is destroyed. I was wondering *which* of the following should I use and, more importantly, *why* should I use it (and *why not* the others).

- Service
- Runnable : A static reference to a Runnable object.  The reference is declared in an Activity class.
- AsyncTask

Comment: Could you elaborate on what this timer app should do? Is it like a stopwatch? An alarmclock?

Comment: what exactly your timer app is doing or you are implementing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909634/service-handler-timer-runnable-which-to-use-and-how

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, I would use a service if your application needs to be able to notify user in background, so if your application has been put in background by the user, you can still notify the user when you timer is ready, and then can use location based event time, etc.

Comment: What about the other option? I'd like the know the pro and con for choosing each option in the app.

Comment: AsyncTask is just a new Thread launched from UI Thread, it as been done mostly to retrieve datas and display it, not for waiting so long, but that would work while the app is launched. Once closed, the thread would quit.

Comment: Runnable is just a code meant to be run on a background Thread, so same principle, it will stop if your app is put in background

Comment: What if I refer to AsyncTask and Runnable with static reference?

Comment: hummm... why would you want a static reference for a Timer task ? If you have only one activity, you can use whatever you want it's going to work, if you are using more than one and want it in your application background, an AsyncTask could work, and you could use Broadcast for saying that your timer is finished, but a proper way would be a well-done service

Comment: There is only one activity but I'm afraid that it might be destroyed when it is not on the top of display stack. If the reference is not static, it will be gone when the activity is destroyed. The broadcast option might not suitable because the app always shows the remaining time.

Answer (score 2):

A Service would be best in this situation, it would, as you require, carry on running even when the main activity is destroyed and would be less prone to being killed by the Android OS.

Both AsyncTask and runnable would rely on your application still being alive, whereas a Service runs independently and you would bind the Activity to it when it is opened or re-started to show information passed from the service, or the service could on it's own, display notifications and so on.

Comment: If I made a static reference to AsyncTask or Runnable, will the object alive as long as my app alive?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to tell you for sure as the Android system decides what should be killed in low memory conditions, but either way you shouldn't be using an AsyncTask for an ongoing process, the point of an AsyncTask is to run a task in the background and execute methods on the UI thread at progress intervals or at the end, if your app was killed, I'm sure the AsyncTask would be along with it.
You really should be using a service for something ongoing. Your objective is to run something even if the activity is destroyed and the service is the activity independant way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Handler, Check here
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Comment: `Handler mHandler` must be static? I'm afraid that when an activity is destroyed, I cannot access the handler.